# Button not playing audio in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, playback

I uploaded a file audio.wav into my supporting files folder.

This is my PlayAudio.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface PlayAudio : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction) PlayIt;

@end
```

This is my PlayAudio.m after the implementation command

```
- (IBAction) PlayIt; {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"audio", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}
```

I then ctrl-clicked from the play button to the First Responder in my view controller and selected PlayIt. I see it's associated with Touch Up Inside.

For some reason I can click the button, but nothing plays. I'm doing this in Storyboard.

Comment: One of my questions is: does iOS know to look in the Supporting Files folder of my project to look for the "audio.wav" file?

Comment: how about trying other players?

Comment: Your implementation of `PlayIt` isn't correct - you have a `;` at the end of the `PlayIt`. Also, please note that Objective-C standards are to use an initial lower-case letter for method names `playIt`. And finally... Have you set breakpoints to check that your code is actually being run and check the values of the variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSURL to get the path of your wav file and cast it to CFURLRef, check the following code:

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSURL *soundPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"wav"]];
if (AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef)soundPath, &soundID) != kAudioServicesNoError) {
     AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(soundID);

}
```

Note, that if mute button on iphone is enable AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID function will fail(Vibration can be used in this case:soundID = kSystemSoundID_Vibrate;). If you want to play sound disregarding the mute switch, use AVAudioPlayer api.